# Disable all selection and onkeypress on mobile version

Tags: bug, mobile-web, javascript

Since today answering questions has become a daunting task. It has never been easy using thus keyboard (Swype), but starting today it's even more difficult.
Before, the application would react randomly on autocorrect and alternative word picking, yet today the alternative word picking consistently /deletes/ the entire message constructed so far and replaces it with the word chosen from the suggestions. Typing this bug , required quite the constraint.

I suggest the events mentioned in the topic be left alone in mobile, our failing that, that users get the option to disable this code.

Note that sites with similar event hooks also give me a headache, including complete browser lockups, like with disquss.

Comment: I can't really understand what the exact problem is. Is it that the Swipe keyboard has a conflict with some mobile apps? We can't really do without those events.